# Upgrade to 14.04 LTS from Windows 7 and 12.10 dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, upgrade, windows-7

I have a dual boot of windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop. I want to upgrade to 14.04 LTS (or any other newer LTS version). My questions are:

1. Do I have to backup my data in Windows 7? (I originally used only Windows 7 and recently, my teacher made the dual boot for me to learn about Ubuntu.)
2. How do I update to version 14.04 LTS without using any CD or USB?

Thank You

Comment: 12.10 is not LTS and why don't you just install 14.04?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you do an In place Upgrade using the procedure suggested in the WIKI. You should be fine. However as a general recommendation you must always backup your data Unless you are 100% sure that whatever you are doing is not going to break your system.

I recommend backing up the Data first, Only then attempt an upgrade. You could also do a clean install of 14.04. Backing up the data should be your first priority before you upgrade anyways.!!